# Ошибка доступа к файлу gl4java

Tags: java, opengl

Возникла ошибка. Как исправить, не знаю. Отзовитесь, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2014/08/70935246a8886d5485910e925d8492cb.png

Comment: Проблема решена изменением настроек приватности в IDE eclipse. Windows>Preferences>Java>Compiler>Errors/Warnings>Deprecated and restricted API>  Изменением на Ignore/Warning с Error

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить из Build Path gl4java.jar и импортировать gl4java заново.